# Angular's createComponent API doesn't work when a component render data

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a ModalService that inserts a modal into document's body. Basically my solution works, but only if the content of the modal is the static HTML. If I'm trying to render some data in the modal, then nothing is displayed

ModalService:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ModalService {
  constructor(
    private appRef: ApplicationRef,
    private injector: EnvironmentInjector
  ) {}

  open(modalBodyType: Type<ElementRef>) {
    const modalContentRef = createComponent(modalBodyType, {
      environmentInjector: this.injector,
    });

    const modalRef = createComponent(ModalComponent, {
      environmentInjector: this.injector,
      projectableNodes: [
        // 1st <ng-content>
        [modalContentRef.location.nativeElement],
      ],
    });

    document.body.appendChild(modalRef.location.nativeElement);
    this.appRef.attachView(modalRef.hostView);
  }
}
```

and I'm trying to display this component with that service:

```
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  template: `Hello`, // this WORKS

  // the line below DOESN'T work
  // template: `Hello {{ name }}!`,
})
export class HelloComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
}
```

if I uncomment the template that renders `name`, then nothing is displayed
What am I doing wrong?

[demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sa8hp6?file=src/app/hello-content.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

You need to trigger the change detection on the projected component for it to evaluate its declarations !

```
  open(modalBodyType: Type<ElementRef>) {
    const modalContentRef = createComponent(modalBodyType, {
      environmentInjector: this.injector,
    });

    const modalRef = createComponent(ModalComponent, {
      environmentInjector: this.injector,
      projectableNodes: [
        // 1st <ng-content>
        [modalContentRef.location.nativeElement],
      ],
    });

    modalContentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges() // here ! 
    document.body.appendChild(modalRef.location.nativeElement);
    this.appRef.attachView(modalRef.hostView);
  }
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work if I set set data asynchronously. I updated my code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sa8hp6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello-content.component.ts

Comment: you'll need to trigger changeDetection after the async data is loaded !

Answer (score -1):

Angular v14.1 added a new function named createComponent. This function can cover the use-cases where the ComponentFactory symbol was previously used.

The function allows creating a ComponentRef instance based on provided Component .

It’s possible to pass a new environment injector inherited from the current one:
CreateComponent service -

```
 import {
    ApplicationRef,
    ComponentRef,
    createComponent,
    EnvironmentInjector,
    Injectable,
  } from '@angular/core';
  import { ContextMenuInputInterface } from './context-menu-interface';
  import { ContextMenuComponent } from './context-menu-items/context-menu.component';
  
  @Injectable(
      { providedIn: 'root' }
  )

  export class ContextMenuService {
    contextMenu: ComponentRef<ContextMenuComponent>;

    constructor(
      private appRef: ApplicationRef,
      private injector: EnvironmentInjector,
    ) {}
  
    open(menuItem: ContextMenuInputInterface[], event: Event) {

      this.close();

      this.contextMenu = createComponent(ContextMenuComponent, {
        environmentInjector: this.injector,
      });

      this.contextMenu.setInput('menuItem', menuItem);
      this.contextMenu.setInput('event', event);
      document.body.appendChild( this.contextMenu.location.nativeElement);
      this.appRef.attachView(this.contextMenu.hostView);

    }
  
    close() {

      this.contextMenu?.destroy();

    }
 

     }
```

How to user this in the application ?
1- Need to import the the service in side the component .

```
import { CreateComponentService } from '…..';
```

2-
In the component -

```
openContextMenu(event: Event): void {

    event.preventDefault();

    const menuItem = [
      {
        displayItem: true,
        disabled: false,
        label: 'Edit',
        icon: 'edit',
        children: [
          {
            displayItem:true,
            action: this.contextMenuActionCopy.bind(null),
            disabled: false,
            label: 'Edit 1',
          },
          {
            displayItem: true,
            action: this.contextMenuActionCopy.bind(null),
            disabled: false,
            label: 'Edit 2',
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        displayItem: false,
        action: this.contextMenuActionCopy.bind(null),
        disabled: false,
        icon: 'content_copy',
        label: 'Copy',
      },
      {
        displayItem: true,
        action: this.contextMenuActionPaste.bind(null),
        disabled: true,
        icon: 'content_paste',
        label: 'Paste',
      },

    ];
// CreateComponent Service 
    this.createComponentService.open(menuItem, event);

  }
```

Need to call "openContextMenu"
[Example link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-edgfvk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcontext-menu%2Fcontext-menu-items%2Fcontext-menu.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fcontext-menu%2Fcontext-menu-items%2Fcontext-menu.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmeterial.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcontext-menu%2Fcontex-menu.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)